# Converting Map to JSON is not resolving lists correctly

Tags: java, json

I am having an issue with creating a new JSON object given a `Map<String, Object>`. For example:

```
Map<String, Object> data = new Map<String, Object>();
data.put( "myList", new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList("item1", "item2")))
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
```

What I am getting with `json.toString()` is

```
"{
  "myList": "[item1, item2]"
 }"
```

when I should be getting

```
"{
  "myList": ["item1", "item2"]
 }"
```

Notice the quotes *around* vs. *in* the array? Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Comment: it can't. you'll have to create the complete structure yourself. Your version of json does not handle nest lists in the `JSONObject` constructor

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your JSON implementation - using wslite, the following code

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put("myList", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("item1", "item2")));
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);

System.out.println(json);
```

leads to

```
{"myList":["item1","item2"]}
```

at my machine.

Comment: same with [Gson](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/) - `System.out.println(gson.toJson(data));`